# Issue with RelativeLayout when View visibility is View.GONE

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've a `RelativeLayout` thus:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<TextView1/>
<TextView2/> // <-- View.VISIBLE OR View.GONE
<TextView3/>
<TextView4/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Each `TextView` is anchored below the previous `TextView` with `android:layout_below`.

The problem is that TextView2 may or may not be there (either `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE`); if it's `View.VISIBLE`, then all is fine, but if it's `View.GONE`, then TextView3 ends up being rendered on top of TextView1.

I've tried various ways to fix this, but each time am caught out by `RelativeLayout`'s 'you cannot reference an id before it's defined' rule.

I'm hoping that I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` has an embedded mechanism for finding closest non-GONE anchor view. I've checked down to Gingerbread and it's present even there: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread-release/core/java/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java#L852

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can place textview 2 and 3 in the LinearLayout and keep the linear layout below textview 1.

Comment: Adding hierarchy to a layout file is always a bad idea especially if it is a RelativeLayout. The more you add the more Android will create Objects to represent your layout. You should use something like android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" instead. You might also consider using other layouts like TableLayout for example.

Answer (score 226):

You can use this tag:

```
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
```

From the docs:

> If set to true, the parent will be used as the anchor when the anchor cannot be be found for layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf, etc.

Comment: This works only when alignment with parent is desired, but the question was about how to align with previous view, not the parent.

Comment: @dismuz, this will be very useful in managing dynamic layouts and avoids any surprises in unforeseen corner cases.

Answer (score 12):

why not update the `below` attribute of TextView3 when you update the visibility of TextView2? (I assume you do this in code)

something like

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.textview1);
((TextView) view).setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 8):

This answer does not solve your specific problem, but does solve a similar one, so hopefully this will help somebody.

I had a situation where my relative layout did not have the equivalent of your TextView1.  So, in my situation, if TextView2 was GONE, then I wanted TextView3 to be aligned with the parent's top.  I solved that by adding to TextView3 the attribute  android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true".  See http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html.

Unfortunately, I do not see a way to specify an alternate alignment anchor unless it is the parent.

Answer (score 7):

Forget about `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`, use this instead:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

params.height = 0;

params.setMargins(0,0,0,0);

view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 7):

you can do this

```
<RelativeLayout>
<TextView1/>
<FrameLayout>
  <TextView2/>  // <-- View.VISIBLE OR View.GONE
</FrameLayout>
<TextView3/>
<TextView4/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

let TextView3 below this FrameLayout which has no background, so if TextView2 is Gone ,it doesn't occupy space.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. All about "alignWithParentIfMissing" is obviously wrong and setting the layout parameter programmatically messes up the code and putting tv2 & tv3 into a linear layout is too much. This one works and is more elegant among other answers.

Answer (score 1):

place all textViews under LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConstraintLayout`, it doesn't break if a referenced view becomes GONE, instead it works as if the size of the hidden view became zero.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#VisibilityBehavior

Answer (score -4):

A simple hack for this is to play with alpha 0/1.
and also disable the onClickListener if there is any

Comment: This will keep the unnecessary space occuped.