# ViewStub ignors alignParentBottom property in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I faced strange ViewStub behavior in RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/stub"
        android:layout="@layout/some_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_above="@id/stub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Some text2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When inflating layout above it looks like viewstub is aligned to parent top but not bottom.
I also have tried to set ViewStub height and width in fixed values (dp or px) but got same result. So is it some kind of Android bug or i missed something with ViewStub?

For example if i'll replace ViewStub with simple View and same RelativeLayout proprties all views infleted in proper way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_above="@id/stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Some text2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**:
I'm not calling inflate on ViewStub. In case inflate method called on ViewStub all works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry bro, I just misunderstood what you mean.

If you see the [Offical Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) , you may see this message "A ViewStub is an invisible, zero-sized View". And let us see some source code in ViewStub:

```
private void initialize(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    setVisibility(GONE);
    setWillNotDraw(true);
}
```

When the ViewStub initialize, it set to `GONE`, That's why your `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` is invalid in `RelativeLayout`.

You can try to use a "Simple View" instead of `ViewStub`, and set that view `visibility` to `GONE`. `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` is also invalid.

So, I don't think this is a Bug!

**Edit:**
I find a similar question:[Issue with RelativeLayout when View visibility is View.GONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279081/issue-with-relativelayout-when-view-visibility-is-view-gone)

And you can add follow code in you "Some text2" TextView, and everything solve!
`android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"`

Comment: Yes you'll get this result if ViewStub will be inflated. But in my case i need to inflate it only in rare cases.

Comment: Hey bro, I just misunderstood and update the Answer.